# Calculate total of two cells in a table for each row based on user select option

Tags: jquery, laravel, vuejs2

I've been struggling with this issue. I have a table with multiple rows. Each row has a quantity (static number), a select box where there are some numbers, and a total column. What I'm trying to do is when a user select a value in dropdown, the quantity will be multiplied by user selection and immediately display results in total column in same row. I tried to use vuejs and jquery and keeps hitting walls.

Here is my vuejs code: please notice the comment

```
<script>
    new Vue({
       el: '#app',
       data: {
           total: ''
       },
        methods: {
          calculateTotal: function(skid, quantity)
          {
              this.total = skid * quantity
          }
        }
    });
</script>

<td>{{$part->skid_quantity}}</td>
                        <td>@{{ total }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('quantity')? ' has-error' : ''}}">
                                <select name="quantity[]" class="form-control" v-on:change="calculateTotal('{{$part->skid_quantity}}','How to get the selected quantity value in the form below for each row')">
                                    @for($i = 0; $i <= $part->quantity; $i++)
                                        <option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>
                                    @endfor
                                </select>
                                {!! Form::hidden('parts_id[]', $part->id) !!}
                                {!! Form::hidden('slug', $category->slug) !!}
                            </div>
                        </td>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in JQuery

```
<tr>
  <td class="fixnumber">5</td>
  <td class="total"></td>
  <td>
      <div class="form-group">
          <select name="quantity[]" class="form-control quantity">
             <option value="none">select an option</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
          </select> 
      </div>
  </td>
</tr>


var select = $(".quantity");
select.on("change", function () {
    $(this).change(function(key, value){
        $(this).closest(".total").text(parseInt($(this).closest(".fixnumber").text())*parseInt($(this).val()))
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in VueJS

```
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            total: '',
            quantity: []
        },
        methods: {
            calculateTotal: function (skid)
            {
                this.total = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < this.quantity.length; i++) {
                    this.total += skid * this.quantity[i];
                }

            }
        }
    });
</script>

<td>{{$part->skid_quantity}}</td>
<td>@{{ total }}</td>
<td>
    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('quantity')? ' has-error' : ''}}">
        <select name="quantity[]" class="form-control" v-on:change="calculateTotal('{{$part->skid_quantity}}')" v-model="quantity">
            @for($i = 0; $i <= $part->quantity; $i++)
            <option v-bind:value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>
            @endfor
        </select>
        {!! Form::hidden('parts_id[]', $part->id) !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('slug', $category->slug) !!}
    </div>
</td>
```